# Two counts in query causing incorrect results

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using

```
SELECT table1.FullName,
  SUM(table2.Asp_PointsAwarded) AS 'Table2 Total Points', 
  table3.Name, 
  table4.Asp_PointsAwarded
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1.ParentCustomerId = table3.AccountId
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ContactId = table2.Asp_SalemadebyId
INNER JOIN table4 ON table1.ContactId = table4.Asp_PointsAwardedToId
WHERE     (table3.asp_mimanagerid = '10CACCBD-70A7-DD11-9C65-001EC9B77038')
GROUP BY table1.FullName, table3.Name, table4.asp_pointsawarded
ORDER BY table1.FullName
```

I get the following results which are correct. 89571 is already summed up correctly:

```
John Doe - 89571 - Contoso - 500
John Doe - 89571 - Contoso - 750
John Doe - 89571 - Contoso - 2000
John Doe - 89571 - Contoso - 26302
John Doe - 89571 - Contoso - 61606
```

However when I try to SUM `table4.Asp_PointsAwarded` using the below code

```
SELECT     table1.FullName, 
  SUM(table2.Asp_PointsAwarded) AS 'Table2 Total Points',
  table3.Name, 
  SUM(table4.Asp_PointsAwarded) AS 'Table4 Total Points'
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1.ParentCustomerId = table3.AccountId
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ContactId = table2.Asp_SalemadebyId
INNER JOIN table4 ON table1.ContactId = table4.Asp_PointsAwardedToId
WHERE     (table3.asp_mimanagerid = '10CACCBD-70A7-DD11-9C65-001EC9B77038')
GROUP BY table1.FullName, table3.Name
ORDER BY table1.FullName
```

I get the following

```
John Doe - 447855 - Contoso - 41568048
```

Any ideas why this is happening? It looks like the 89571 has been added up again 5 times which I do not want to happen. Ideally I want to see the following output:

```
John Doe - 89571 - Contoso - 91158
```

Comment: You need to properly format your code and re paste it in.

Comment: You're summing duplicate rows because you took asp_pointsawarded out of the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `join` repeats all matching rows in the right hand table for each row in the left hand table.  If you do two joins, it repeats all rows in the third table, for all rows in the second table, for all rows in the first table.  That means counts go way wrong.

You can solve this by summing before joining:

```
SELECT  table1.FullName
,       sub1.sum_points
,       table3.Name
,       sub2.sum_points
FROM    table1
JOIN    table3
ON      table1.ParentCustomerId = table3.AccountId
JOIN    (
        SELECT  Asp_SalemadebyId
        ,       SUM(Asp_PointsAwarded) sum_points
        FROM    table2
        GROUP BY
                Asp_SalemadebyId
        ) sub1 
ON      table1.ContactId = sub1.Asp_SalemadebyId
JOIN    (
        SELECT  Asp_PointsAwardedToId
        ,       SUM(Asp_PointsAwarded) sum_points
        FROM    table4
        GROUP BY
                Asp_PointsAwardedToId
        ) sub2
ON      table1.ContactId = sub2.Asp_PointsAwardedToId
WHERE   table3.asp_mimanagerid = '10CACCBD-70A7-DD11-9C65-001EC9B77038')
```

Comment: This has worked perfectly. Thanks very much for your detailed answer, you have helped me understand what I was doing wrong.

And thanks for the crash course in proper SQL code layout, mine is awful at the best of times!